# Gnome panel and menu bar can't be clicked..!

Tags: package-management, system-installation, mouse, gnome-panel

I am using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.  I installed it using the feature 'Install within Windows'. I got a simple though difficult problem.

---

The touchpad and external mouse movements are working fine.

### I am able to :

- Maximize, minimize, and close an opened window using the buttons on the window.
- Drag a window by double-clicking and holding it.
- Rise up a context menu with a right-click on the window border.
- Scroll through a page with the Mouse wheel.

### I am not able to :

- Left-click or right-click on a panel.
- Open a menu item from the menu bar using a click.
- Open a folder by double-clicking it.
- Rise up a context menu for a right-click inside the window area.
- Click an item in the side pane.
- Scroll through a page by dragging the scroll bar.
- Select **OK** or **cancel** in the pop-up windows with a click. [To do so, I have to use `tab` to go to the option and press enter].

---

### It happened as follows :

I finished installing the packages `planets`, `sugar-emulator`, `rlplot`, `gsynaptics`, then opened the package `planets`, and added a planet in the opened window.

**The `planets` window said to press `Ctrl + Shift` to release the mouse from its window to a normal ubuntu environment. I doubt my keystroke was wrong. I am not sure what I pressed. Something wrong went from there. **

I thought a restart would clear the problem, but it didn't. I removed all the installed packages and their dependencies and restarted my laptop. Still, the problem exists.

I am using my laptop with all the keyboard shortcuts I know. And I have to press `tab` many times to select something and it is really bad.

### Solution?

1. Should I install any drivers for my touchpad?
2. Is there any option to restore my system to an earlier point in time as is possible in windows?
3. Should I change any settings?
4. Can I recover using any bootup installation?

Comment: Does this happen after a reboot? Does this happen in the guest session or logged in as another user?

Comment: @Martin Yes, happened after a reboot too. No, not in a guest session or not logged in as another user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your gnome settings are corrupted some how. Instead of spending time debugging them all, your quickest solution is to create a new user and move over your document files. The other option is to try and reset the options for gnome:

From a terminal which you can get to by going Applications > Accessories > Terminal, copy and paste the following:

`rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`

This will remove all of your gnome settings and set them to the default settings. These files are normally hidden files and you don't normally see them in your home folder from nautilus (nautilus is the file manager that is shown when you go to Places > Home).

Log off and back on to apply the changes.

Comment: @Martin I will consider what you said.

Comment: @Martin I now created a new user account, say 'user2'. I gave the 'user2' with administrator privileges. I didn't even copy my documents stored under 'user', still I can access them from  **/home/user/**. Anyways, you said to delete settings folder going to nautilus. Can u tell me how i can go to nautilus.? Using **root** ? Since no problem exists in 'user2' account, i would like to ask u, "Is there a way to reset an user's settings or changing them to default.?"

Comment: @Vinay - I've updated my instructions.

Comment: @Martin I got my doubt cleared. I knew what nautilus is. But, i thought that i should go and edit files in a folder like */root/bin/nautilus/* some kind of them. I now came to know that, these files are hidden in the */home/* folder.
My problem is now solved. I thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: Can you re-title the question for me so others can find it? Something like: "Gnome panel and menu bar can't be clicked"

Comment: @Martin I edited the title and added *gnome-panel* to tags.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem was very simple

```
Click in the menu
"System"
"Preferences"
"Windows"
Then under "Movement Key"
select the radio button for "super (or "Windows Logo")
```

I don't know if this is the way it is supposed to be set or if it is backwards now (I never looked at this setting before) but my mouse now works correctly on
Ubuntu 10.04

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1512841

Answer (score 1):

**Try to kill and re-run your panel app process.**

**Can't run terminal?**

If you are unable to start the Terminal (e.g. using a shortcut Alt+F2), but can run file manager,

you can find the Terminal in: **`/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`** (or generally in **`/usr/bin/*`**)

1. Search for a panel process (e.g. gnome-system-monitor > tab "Processes", search for something *-panel), for me it was `xfce4-panel`, for you it is probably `gnome-panel`
2. Run terminal
3. Kill all of it: `sudo killall gnome-panel`
4. Start it again `sudo gnome-panel &`

If you have **Xubuntu**, your panel app process is probably `xfce4-panel`, then, of course:

`sudo killall xfce4-panel`

`sudo xfce4-panel &`

Answer (score 0):

At least for the panel, you should try restarting the panel via "gnome-panel --replace" command to see if this temporary solves your problem (until next restart). In Ubuntu 10.04 my Desktop didn't have any problems, but with my Laptop, 80% of times I had to restart the panel at boot time ( there was a bug in gnome ).

If @Martin Owens solution doesn't work you could use KDE for a while ( it will be easier to have a working station to help you find a solution, that what I did in 10.10, where in gnome the mouse could not click anything but in KDE worked ). KDE is instaled from software center as kubuntu package, or in CLI with this command :sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

Comment: This won't work, gnome-panel --replace will only reload the saved settings, so if a reboot won't solve it, this certainly won't.

Comment: @Martin Yes, it didn't. But, the panel just got reloaded with its settings.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the behavior mentioned here, happened to me as well in while using Xubuntu 18.04, I solved it by going into the XFCE Panel Switch and reapplying my current configuration.

Hope it helps.