# Mouse clicks do not work for native ubuntu apps or when open folder/file from third-party apps

Tags: 18.04, unity, mouse, system

I can not open files or folders from apps like rstudio, typora or chrome. As shown below, when I click "open folders" from typora, the dark grey box will pop up. However, all the buttons do not respond to mouse click except the 'Cancel', so that I can not switch folders or select a file.

[image]

Similarly, when I open the settings from top menu bar, all the buttons do not respond except the option to close it. If I move the window, it appears as follows:

[image]

Restart will temporarily solve the problem. But It will start behaving like this again several days later.

I can't find a solution on the web. Any help is appreciated.

---

What I have tried:

I renamed `.gnome .gnome2 .gconf` (the other two folders were not found) following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/13311/599931).

Clear cache following this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system).